# Get the error "ERC1155: caller not owner or approved" even after calling setApprovalForAll function

Tags: remix, nft, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, erc-1155

I have a question about the openzeppelin erc1155.sol contract. It is regarding operator approval and the safeTransferFrom() function. I am trying to do an ERC1155 token transfer and keep getting the error "ERC1155: caller is not owner or approved" even though I tried calling the setApprovalForAll function for the correct address before. I took a deeper look into it and found the following:

If you take a look at the source code over here:
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol

the setApprovalForAll(address operator,bool approved) function updates _operatorApprovals[_msgSender()][operator] = approved.

If you then take a look at safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 id, uint256 amount, bytes memory data)
The require statement in this function basically checks if isApprovedForAll(from, _msgSender()) is true. But shouldn't it check isApprovedForAll(_msgSender(),from) instead??

The isApprovedForAll(address account, address operator) checks if _operatorApprovals[account][operator] is true or false.. but like i mentioned before when we call the setApprovalForAll function, the transposed is updated.. am I overlooking something.. or could it be that open zeppelin may have made a mistake? Any help would be greatly appreciated :smile:

Comment: I doubt that OpenZeppelin contract has that kind of mistakes. Are you calling `setApprovalForAll` from a contract? A contract cannot approve itself on behalf of the token owner. The token owner has to approve manually the contract.